# Is it possible to use Foundation semantic grid mixins inside mediaqueries?

Tags: css, sass, frontend, zurb-foundation

I've made a small example grid with the foundation framework(http://foundation.zurb.com/). The grid is made out of four floating elements on a desktop mode(_setting, $rowWidth 1140px)

*markup

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="main">
       <div id="column">
```

*scss

```
   #container{
        @include outerRow(); 
    }
   .column{
        @include column(3);
    }
```

Above mixins based on these sources: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass-mixins.php

Now I want to change the column structure when the example will be viewed on a tablet in portrait mode. I've made something like this:

```
@media screen  and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {

    #container{
      @include outerRow(); 
    }
   .column{
          @include column(6);
    }

}
```

The following error occurs:

```
>     DEPRECATION WARNING on line 21 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/zurb-foundation-3.2.3/scss/foundation/mixins/_semantic-grid.scss:
>       @extending an outer selector from within @media is deprecated.
>       You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
>       This will be an error in Sass 3.3.
>       It can only work once @extend is supported natively in the browser.
```

Can anybody tell me what the working method is to re-define the column structure for each different media query in a foundation based project?

Comment: Where are those mixins defined?  Source needed.

Comment: Semantic grid mixins are defined here. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass-mixins.php

Comment: A list of mixin names and a vague description of what they do is not the source.  Please provide a link the *actual* source to speed up the answering process in the future.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. It's currently only living on my local machine. I suggest you grab a copy of foundation(http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/compass.php) and follow the steps I've write down above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, all you should need to do is redefine the extend mixins like `%clearfix` within your media query.  If those classes are defined within another file, importing the file would also work (provided you aren't placing it within some sort of control block, like an if/else statement).

Looking at the source of the project, what you're looking to do probably shouldn't be done that way (see:  https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/mixins/_semantic-grid.scss)

Both of the mixins referenced in your sample code generate their own media queries, so avoid invoking them twice on the same element or you'll end up with a lot of duplicate/unused CSS.  Instead, just overwrite the properties that actually need modifying:

```
.exampleA {
    @include outerRow();

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
        // do not @include outerRow() again here!
        // these are the only properties that are variable in the outerRow() mixin:
        width: $tabletWidth;
        min-width: $tabletMinWidth;
    }
}
```

The other thing you need to realize is that once you've defined your `$totalColumns`, you're stuck with it when using the `column` mixin (see: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/mixins/_semantic-grid.scss#L64 and https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/mixins/_semantic-grid.scss#L19).  You can't have 6 total columns by default and then 4 for your tablet.  If you need to be able to this, you could simply run the `gridCalc()` function yourself:

```
.exampleB {
    @include column(6);

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
        width: gridCalc(2, 6); // columns, totalColumns
    }
}
```

If you're ok with the number of `$totalColumns` for your media query, pass `$totalColumns` as the 2nd argument.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! This is helpfull for what I want to do.

Comment: FYI all these links are dead